# Spring integration Kafka and managing offsets

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, apache-kafka

I'm using Spring Integration Kafka extension to read and process messages from the Kafka in Java application. As I know it uses high-level consumer API that doesn't allow fully manage offsets in Zookeeper.

In my case we have **auto.commit.enable**=false in order to commit offset to Zookeeper after message is processed. If processing fails then offset won't be committed and we should try to process same message again in some configured time starting with offset from Zookeeper. But it doesn't work because, I assume, Apache Kafka client keeps offset in memory.

I've found out that *kafka.consumer.ConsumerIterator* handles offsets and if **consumedOffset** in it greater than in Zookeeper then it will read message using consumed one.

So, I'm wondering are there any ways to reset offset in Kafka client to start reading from offset which is in Zookeeper?

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you mind to share your `<int-kafka>` config and point out where do you have an issue?

Maybe it will be just enough to do this `MessageLeftOverTracker.clearMessagesLeftOver()` ?

I'm not well with Kafka, but know what Spring Integration does.